# PHP Array last element being lost from using another array as dictionary

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

I have three arrays. One that contains the given title information from the user stored in $attributenames. The second has the data from the user stored in $anesdata. (So the first two are related) And the third is a dictionary so that I can get out the information I want using the index which is stored in $medicalInstanceDictionary.

This is the first one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PATIENT MRN
    [1] => PATIENT LAST NAME
    [2] => PATIENT FIRST NAME
    [3] => PATIENT MIDDLE NAME
    [4] => PATIENT SSN
    [5] => PATIENT SEX
    [6] => INVOICE
    [7] => TRANSACTION
    [8] => DATE OF PROCEDURE
    [9] => POSTING DATE
    [10] => LOCATION
    [11] => CHARGE AMT
    [12] => PROVIDER
    [13] => FSC1
    [14] => FSC2
    [15] => PATIENT DOB
    [16] => ATTENDING SURGEON
    [17] => ATTENDING SURGEON
    [18] => CPT CODES
    [19] => ASA CLASSFICATION
    [20] => ANESTHESIA CRNA
    [21] => ANESTHESIA RESIDENT
    [22] => SURGERY START TIME
    [23] => SURGERY END TIME
    [24] => SVC UNIT
    [25] => FACILITY NAME
    [26] => BILLING NUMBER
    [27] => BILLING AREA NAME
    [28] => PROCEDURE MODIFIER1
    [29] => PROCEDURE MODIFIER2
    [30] => PROCEDURE MODIFIER3
    [31] => PRIMARY DX
    [32] => SECONDARY DX

)
```

The second array is a two dimensional array, but each line is equivalent to one patient. So that first patient looks like this(put in x's instead of actual patient data):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => xxxx
        [1] => xxxx
        [2] => xxxx
        [3] => xxxx
        [4] => xxxxx
        [5] => xxxx
        [6] => xxxx
        [7] => xxx
        [8] => xxxxx
        [9] => xxxx
        [10] => xxxx
        [11] => xxxxx
        [12] => xxxx
        [13] => xxxxx
        [14] => xxxx
        [15] => xxxx
        [16] => xxxxxxx
        [17] => xxxxx
        [18] => xxxxx
        [19] => xxxx
        [20] => 
        [21] => xxxxx
        [22] => xxxxx
        [23] => xxxxx
        [24] => xxxxx
        [25] => xxxx
        [26] => xxxxx
        [27] => xxxx
        [28] => xxxxxxxx
        [29] => xxxx
        [30] => 
        [31] => xxxxxxx
        [32] => xxxxxxx

    )
```

Then the dictionary looks like this:

```
$medicalInstanceDictionary = array(
    'CPT CODES' => "CPT_Code",
    'ASA CLASSFICATION' => "MG_ASA_Class",
    'FACILITY NAME' => "Facility_Name",
    'BILLING NUMBER' => "Billing_Number",
    'BILLING AREA NAME' => "Billing_Area_Name",
    'PROCEDURE MODIFIER1' => "Procedure_Modifier1",
    'PROCEDURE MODIFIER2' => "Procedure_Modifier2",
    'PRIMARY DX' => "Primary_Dx",
    'SECONDARY DX' => "Secondary_Dx",
    'INVOICE' => "FIN"
);
```

I am doing a nested foreach loop to get each row.

```
foreach ($dataarray as $dataindex => $datavalue)
{
    $out = "";
    foreach ($dictionary as $index => $value)
    {
        //find PATIENT MRN in $attributearray and get it's index
        $attributeindex = array_search($index, $attributearray);
        if ($attributeindex===FALSE) {
            echo "Error : ".$index." not found <br />";
        } else { 
            echo "<br>The attribute is: ".$value." The index is: ".$attributeindex."<br>";
        }

(more code....)
}
(more code....)
}
```

That echo statement looks like this:

```
The attribute is: CPT_Code The index is: 18

The attribute is: MG_ASA_Class The index is: 19

The attribute is: Facility_Name The index is: 25

The attribute is: Billing_Number The index is: 26

The attribute is: Billing_Area_Name The index is: 27

The attribute is: Procedure_Modifier1 The index is: 28

The attribute is: Procedure_Modifier2 The index is: 29

The attribute is: Primary_Dx The index is: 31
Error : SECONDARY DX not found

The attribute is: FIN The index is: 6
```

I have no idea why it is skipping over Secondary_Dx. I have checked for spelling errors. I don't think it is my method of doing it because it only does not work for Secondary_Dx. The only thing I can think of is that it does something funky since it is the last element of the array. Has anyone seen this before?

Edit:
Added element(tried both methods, and both resulted in the same looking array using print_r:

```
//array_push($attributenames, "THE END");
$attributenames[] ="THE END";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($attributenames);
echo "</pre>";
```

output from that along with the error handling statement from above:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PATIENT MRN
    [1] => PATIENT LAST NAME
    [2] => PATIENT FIRST NAME
    [3] => PATIENT MIDDLE NAME
    [4] => PATIENT SSN
    [5] => PATIENT SEX
    [6] => INVOICE
    [7] => TRANSACTION
    [8] => DATE OF PROCEDURE
    [9] => POSTING DATE
    [10] => LOCATION
    [11] => CHARGE AMT
    [12] => PROVIDER
    [13] => FSC1
    [14] => FSC2
    [15] => PATIENT DOB
    [16] => ATTENDING SURGEON
    [17] => ATTENDING SURGEON
    [18] => CPT CODES
    [19] => ASA CLASSFICATION
    [20] => ANESTHESIA CRNA
    [21] => ANESTHESIA RESIDENT
    [22] => SURGERY START TIME
    [23] => SURGERY END TIME
    [24] => SVC UNIT
    [25] => FACILITY NAME
    [26] => BILLING NUMBER
    [27] => BILLING AREA NAME
    [28] => PROCEDURE MODIFIER1
    [29] => PROCEDURE MODIFIER2
    [30] => PROCEDURE MODIFIER3
    [31] => PRIMARY DX
    [32] => SECONDARY DX

    [33] => THE END
)


This is dictionary array Array
(
    [CPT CODES] => CPT_Code
    [ASA CLASSFICATION] => MG_ASA_Class
    [FACILITY NAME] => Facility_Name
    [BILLING NUMBER] => Billing_Number
    [BILLING AREA NAME] => Billing_Area_Name
    [PROCEDURE MODIFIER1] => Procedure_Modifier1
    [PROCEDURE MODIFIER2] => Procedure_Modifier2
    [PRIMARY DX] => Primary_Dx
    [SECONDARY DX] => Secondary_Dx
    [INVOICE] => FIN
)


The attribute is: CPT_Code The index is: 18

The attribute is: MG_ASA_Class The index is: 19

The attribute is: Facility_Name The index is: 25

The attribute is: Billing_Number The index is: 26

The attribute is: Billing_Area_Name The index is: 27

The attribute is: Procedure_Modifier1 The index is: 28

The attribute is: Procedure_Modifier2 The index is: 29

The attribute is: Primary_Dx The index is: 31
Error : SECONDARY DX not found
Array ( [0] => PATIENT MRN [1] => PATIENT LAST NAME [2] => PATIENT FIRST NAME [3] => PATIENT MIDDLE NAME [4] => PATIENT SSN [5] => PATIENT SEX [6] => INVOICE [7] => TRANSACTION [8] => DATE OF PROCEDURE [9] => POSTING DATE [10] => LOCATION [11] => CHARGE AMT [12] => PROVIDER [13] => FSC1 [14] => FSC2 [15] => PATIENT DOB [16] => ATTENDING SURGEON [17] => ATTENDING SURGEON [18] => CPT CODES [19] => ASA CLASSFICATION [20] => ANESTHESIA CRNA [21] => ANESTHESIA RESIDENT [22] => SURGERY START TIME [23] => SURGERY END TIME [24] => SVC UNIT [25] => FACILITY NAME [26] => BILLING NUMBER [27] => BILLING AREA NAME [28] => PROCEDURE MODIFIER1 [29] => PROCEDURE MODIFIER2 [30] => PROCEDURE MODIFIER3 [31] => PRIMARY DX [32] => SECONDARY DX [33] => THE END )
Array ( [CPT CODES] => CPT_Code [ASA CLASSFICATION] => MG_ASA_Class [FACILITY NAME] => Facility_Name [BILLING NUMBER] => Billing_Number [BILLING AREA NAME] => Billing_Area_Name [PROCEDURE MODIFIER1] => Procedure_Modifier1 [PROCEDURE MODIFIER2] => Procedure_Modifier2 [PRIMARY DX] => Primary_Dx [SECONDARY DX] => Secondary_Dx [INVOICE] => FIN )
The attribute is: FIN The index is: 6
```

Comment: Have a look at [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: which of the three arrays is $attributearray? maybe it will help if you pass the whole code...

Comment: The first one is $attributearray. I thought about putting in the whole code but there are multiple files and it looks kinds messy.

Comment: Okay, added in the break and dictionary, changed the output above.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Can you see the empty line between the output print_r($attributenames); [32] and [33] ? There is a non visual character maybe a new line.

Comment: Where in your code do you create, or get , the $attributearray ??

Comment: Thank you a lot, I took the new line off of the end of the element and it works! If you change your answer to reflect that I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad we got it to work . I just wait till you read my comment. And then point you to `bin2hex` to see all the char in the variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks. What do you mean by this: Where 0d is CR and 0a is LF .

Comment: Please look at my updated answer. You should accept my answer . I have spent a lot of time to find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test for a valid `$attributeindex` !

```
 $attributeindex = array_search($index, $attributearray);

 if ($attributeindex===FALSE) {
    echo "Error : ".$index." not found <br />";
   } else { 
    echo "<br>The attribute is: ".$value." The index is: ".$attributeindex."<br>";
   }
```

If you get a not found Error you can be shure `$index` is not found in `$attributearray` .

**Update :**

This is very strange !
From your output we can clearly see.
`$index == SECONDARY DX`

and
$attributearray has a key [32]
`[32] => SECONDARY DX`

Only to test :
can you add to $attributearray at the end
`[33] => 'END'`

and see what happens.

**Update 2 :**

As i can see in the new output you got with

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($attributenames);
echo "</pre>";
```

There is a empty line between [32] and [33].
There must be a invisible sign at the end of `[32] => SECONDARY DX`
I suspect a new line character.

```
Array
(
    [0] => PATIENT MRN
    [1] => PATIENT LAST NAME
    ....
    [30] => PROCEDURE MODIFIER3
    [31] => PRIMARY DX
    [32] => SECONDARY DX

    [33] => THE END
)
```

Try to remove that character and it should work .

**TIP:**

If you ever re experiencing similar behavior, you should check with :

for example:

```
echo bin2hex($attributenames[32]);
```

Output in windows look at the end :

```
5345434f4e444152592044580d0a
```

Where `0d` is `CR` = `Carriage return` and `0a` is `LF` = `Line feed` .

ASCII-Tabelle

[image]

Comment: I don't think this would be helpful, because I know that $index is in $attributearray. I have used this code before and it works for everything else, just not Secondary_Dx.

Comment: `You should always Test it` OR can you use `FALSE` . You will see what is in $index . And then show us what you got.

Comment: I can't tell what you mean. when I do print_R($attributearray) it comes out looking like the first array I have above. You can't break down print_r when you are outputting it to test for errors right?

Comment: you can't stop print_r() from outputting. Can you show the output you get (only the last lines) ?

Comment: I updated it so there is current code and current output at the end of the post. I still don't understand what you are looking for. That output does not seem useful to me. Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean? What I showed above is the output from one of the loops running `print_r($attributearray);` I copied and pasted it from the browser.

Comment: Updated the current code and current output sections to show $dictionary

Comment: Okay! posted my update above, added another element, still is not finding Secondary_Dx. I agree, very strange!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `trim()` on the value you are testing for. If there is white space you can't see at the end it won't match.

```
$attributeindex = trim( array_search($index, $attributearray) );
```